# Simple z-index example not working - still wrong order

Tags: html, css

EDIT: Added code and JS-fiddle

I know this is a common question but I have read all the other related questions and I can't seem to work it out. Sorry if I am being dumb?

why is item A above the button div when the z-indexs should mean otherwise?

[image]

```
<html lang="en">
<body>
  <div class="RadioContainer">
  <div class="RadioButton"> Click Here to Choose </div>
  <div class="AnItem" style="transform: translateY(-4.32px); z-index: -1;"> Item A </div>
  <div class="AnItem" style="transform: translateY(-4.32px); z-index: -2;"> Item B </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

```
.Centerer {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.RadioContainer {
    display: inline-block;
}

.RadioButton {
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: white;
}

.AnItem {
    background-color: darkgrey;
}

.TopHalf {
    height: 50vh;
}
```

Here is a JS-fiddle version

https://jsfiddle.net/jwz5v2xr/

Comment: What do you want to achieve? and there is nothing called `z-index:-2;` also did you know that  `z-index` to get to work you have to use few `position` properties?

Comment: What do you mean there is nothing called z-index:-2?   and what position properties do I need to use?

Comment: In radio-button class you need to add "position: relative".

Comment: You can start from here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index, and this is the comment from w3schools `z-index only works on positioned elements (position: absolute, position: relative, position: fixed, or position: sticky).` https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Comment: Ok I didn't realise that static was the default

Answer (score 1):

```css
.Centerer {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.RadioContainer {
    display: inline-block;
}

.RadioButton {
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: white;
    position: relative;
}

.AnItem {
    background-color: darkgrey;
}

.TopHalf {
    height: 50vh;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<body>
  <div class="RadioContainer">
  <div class="RadioButton"> Click Here to Choose </div>
  <div class="AnItem" style="transform: translateY(-4.32px); z-index: -1;"> Item A </div>
  <div class="AnItem" style="transform: translateY(-4.32px); z-index: -2;"> Item B </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I have added "position: relative;".